# c# parent-child property protection

Tags: c#, parent-child, encapsulation

Here are two classes with a parent/child relation (taken from Unity3D)

```
public class GameObject
{
    ...
    public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component;
    ...
}

public class Component
{
    ...
    public GameObject gameObject { get; }
    ...
}
```

Since only the getter is public, how do they acheive to set the value of the Component gameObject field ? (There is no other methods in the Component class that takes a GameObject)

I'm asking this because I use the same kind of design and I want to make the setter private.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could have an `internal` setter, or it could be that the `GameObject` is passed into the constructor and set there? Or it could use reflection to set the field directly (or call an otherwise unavailable accessor), but I rather doubt it.

Comment: I was also thinking about the constructor, but the class metadata contains only a default constructor.
You must be right about the internal setter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a component to the GameObject, there is most likely an internal setter that assigns the parent(GameObject) of the component. So in this case the only way to set the GameObject of a component is to add the component to the GameObject.

You could compare to winForms where if you add a child control to a parent control's control collection, the parent of the child control is set for you.

Comment: It must be internal indeed.
For controls in winform, the setter of the Parent property is public :
public Control Parent { get; set; }
Thanks